# Eigen: Modify Rows of Row-Major Sparse Matrix

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I am using the Eigen library in C++ for solving sparse linear equations: Ax=b where, A is a square sparse matrix and b is a dense vector with ILU-preconditioned BiCGSTAB. I am initializing the matrix A using the `setFromTriplets` function. The linear system is generated from discretization of partial differential equations in space and time.

My application changes the matrix slightly at every time-step. I want to modify a small number of rows (around 1% rows) in the matrix in the beginning of each time-step. I am storing the matrix in the row-major format so that I can access the row directly. I don't want to re-assemble the entire matrix from triplets since the number of rows to be modified are around 1%. Moreover, the modification is such that the number of non-zeros in the row are exactly identical. I just want to change the column indices and values. Hence, I do not need to allocate extra memory for the row. After going through the Eigen documentation as well as the forum, I found the functions `coeffRef` and `insert`. Both of them will allocate extra memory if the element does not exist. I would like to avoid this since the number of non-zeros are not changing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I recommend looking at how the matrix is stored internally and directly modify the inner indices and values corresponding to the rows you want to change. There is no "easy" API for that at the moment. If you think this is more commonly needed, you could make a feature request for this.